# Create "Custom Action Group" in "Site Actions" menu

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-actions

I want to list my "Custom Action" as the first item in the "Site Action" menu, so I thought of creating a new "Custom Action Group" and inside the group, I will add my "Custom Action" using the below code in *elements.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

<CustomActionGroup
  Description = "Display the Site Owner's Name, SharePoint Group and E-mail ID"
  Id = "SiteActions1"
  Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
  Sequence = "0"
  Title = "View Site Owner(S)">
</CustomActionGroup>
<CustomAction
    Id="ViewSiteOwner"
    GroupId="SiteActions1"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="0"
    Title="View Site Owner"
    Description="Display the Site Owner's Name, SharePoint Group and E-mail ID." >
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('{SiteUrl}/_Layouts/15/Common/SiteOwnerPage.aspx?IsDlg=1','RefreshOnDialogClose',600, 200,'View Site Owner')"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

But for some reason, it doesn't create custom group and the custom action, so I removed the "Custom Action Group" and created a custom action with the sequence to be "0", **but SharePoint for some reason it displays as the last item in the menu,**

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="ViewSiteOwner"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="20"
    Title="View Site Owner"
    Description="Display the Site Owner's Name, SharePoint Group and E-mail ID." >
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('{SiteUrl}/_Layouts/15/Common/SiteOwnerPage.aspx?IsDlg=1','RefreshOnDialogClose',600, 200,'View Site Owner')"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Is it a bug in SharePoint or is this how it works.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is intended or not, but that is the way it works.

If you want to add a custom action to the site action menu on a different place then the last one.  You need to follow [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108455/custom-site-action-flyout-menu) method. This is for sp2010.